# Compile evolution development snapshot 3.13.1

Tags: gnome, 14.04, compiling, dependencies, evolution

I have downloaded evolution development snapshot from this link: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evolution and now I have trouble compiling the source code. I am using ubuntu 14.04 and this version of evolution needs newer packages which are not available on ubuntu 14.04 repository (at least I did not find).

How could I find and install those dependencies without messing up my packages?

Output from auto-apt run ./configure

```
mehdix@werkstatt:~/Downloads/evolution-3.13.1$ auto-apt run ./configure
Entering auto-apt mode: ./configure
Exit the command to leave auto-apt mode.
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for supported compiler flags...  -Wall -Wextra -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wformat-security -Winit-self -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wmissing-noreturn -Wnested-externs -Wpointer-arith -Wredundant-decls -Wundef -Wwrite-strings
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... (cached) gcc3
checking for inline... inline
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking whether gcc and cc understand -c and -o together... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking for gawk... (cached) mawk
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.16... yes
checking whether NLS is requested... yes
checking for intltool >= 0.40.0... 0.50.2 found
checking for intltool-update... /usr/bin/intltool-update
checking for intltool-merge... /usr/bin/intltool-merge
checking for intltool-extract... /usr/bin/intltool-extract
checking for xgettext... /usr/bin/xgettext
checking for msgmerge... /usr/bin/msgmerge
checking for msgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for gmsgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for perl >= 5.8.1... 5.18.2
checking for XML::Parser... ok
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
checking for pkg-config... (cached) /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking whether to build with code coverage support... no
checking for itstool... itstool
checking for xmllint... xmllint
checking for gtkdoc-check... no
checking for gtkdoc-rebase... no
checking for gtkdoc-mkpdf... no
checking whether to build gtk-doc documentation... no
checking for Win32... no
checking for nl_langinfo... yes
checking for nl_langinfo (_NL_MEASUREMENT_MEASUREMENT)... yes
checking for GNOME_PLATFORM... no
configure: error: Package requirements (gio-2.0 >= 2.36.0
     gmodule-2.0 >= 2.36.0
     cairo-gobject
     gtk+-3.0 >= 3.8.0
     gail-3.0 >= 3.8.0
     gdk-pixbuf-2.0 >= 2.24.0
     gcr-3 >= 3.4
     libxml-2.0 >= 2.7.3
     shared-mime-info >= 0.22
     gnome-desktop-3.0 >= 2.91.3
     gsettings-desktop-schemas >= 2.91.92
     webkitgtk-3.0 >= 2.0.1) were not met:

No package 'cairo-gobject' found
No package 'gtk+-3.0' found
No package 'gail-3.0' found
No package 'gdk-pixbuf-2.0' found
No package 'gcr-3' found
No package 'libxml-2.0' found
No package 'gnome-desktop-3.0' found
No package 'gsettings-desktop-schemas' found
No package 'webkitgtk-3.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables GNOME_PLATFORM_CFLAGS
and GNOME_PLATFORM_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
mehdix@werkstatt:~/Downloads/evolution-3.13.1$
```

EDIT:
I did sudo apt-get build-dep evolution and this issue solved but now I have another issue:

```
    mehdix@werkstatt:~/Downloads/evolution-3.13.1$ auto-apt run ./configure
Entering auto-apt mode: ./configure
Exit the command to leave auto-apt mode.
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for supported compiler flags...  -Wall -Wextra -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wformat-security -Winit-self -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wmissing-noreturn -Wnested-externs -Wpointer-arith -Wredundant-decls -Wundef -Wwrite-strings
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... (cached) gcc3
checking for inline... inline
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking whether gcc and cc understand -c and -o together... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking for gawk... (cached) mawk
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.16... yes
checking whether NLS is requested... yes
checking for intltool >= 0.40.0... 0.50.2 found
checking for intltool-update... /usr/bin/intltool-update
checking for intltool-merge... /usr/bin/intltool-merge
checking for intltool-extract... /usr/bin/intltool-extract
checking for xgettext... /usr/bin/xgettext
checking for msgmerge... /usr/bin/msgmerge
checking for msgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for gmsgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for perl >= 5.8.1... 5.18.2
checking for XML::Parser... ok
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
checking for pkg-config... (cached) /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking whether to build with code coverage support... no
checking for itstool... itstool
checking for xmllint... xmllint
checking for gtkdoc-check... /usr/bin/gtkdoc-check
checking for gtkdoc-rebase... /usr/bin/gtkdoc-rebase
checking for gtkdoc-mkpdf... /usr/bin/gtkdoc-mkpdf
checking whether to build gtk-doc documentation... no
checking for Win32... no
checking for nl_langinfo... yes
checking for nl_langinfo (_NL_MEASUREMENT_MEASUREMENT)... yes
checking for GNOME_PLATFORM... yes
checking for EVOLUTION_DATA_SERVER... no
configure: error: Package requirements (camel-1.2 >= 3.13.1
     libebook-1.2 >= 3.13.1
     libecal-1.2 >= 3.13.1
     libedataserver-1.2 >= 3.13.1
     libebackend-1.2 >= 3.13.1) were not met:

Requested 'camel-1.2 >= 3.13.1' but version of camel is 3.10.4
Requested 'libebook-1.2 >= 3.13.1' but version of libebook is 3.10.4
Requested 'libecal-1.2 >= 3.13.1' but version of libecal is 3.10.4
Requested 'libedataserver-1.2 >= 3.13.1' but version of libedataserver is 3.10.4
Requested 'libebackend-1.2 >= 3.13.1' but version of libebackend is 3.10.4

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables EVOLUTION_DATA_SERVER_CFLAGS
and EVOLUTION_DATA_SERVER_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
mehdix@werkstatt:~/Downloads/evolution-3.13.1$ sudo apt-get build-dep
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem. First I installed as much dependencies as possible using

```
sudo apt-get build-dep evolution
```

Then still there was some dependencies which was because of newer required packages which I installed using ppa at this address:
    https://launchpad.net/~fta/+archive/gnome3

Then with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` the `./configure` problem was solved.